# MySQL AES_DECRYPT in NodeJS, placeholder for encryption key?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I found similar replies but nothing really straightforward.
How can AES_DECRYPT be used only for the password field in a query using MySQL extension in NodeJS ?
What I have is as follow:

```
app.post("/verify",function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT *, FROM `bosses` where u=? and p=?', [req.body.user,req.body.pass], function (error, results, fields) {
            if(results.length){
                session.loggedin=1;
                res.redirect('/zirkus');
            }else{
                res.redirect('/soccer');
            }
        });
```

I assume that I need to modify the query with something like this:

```
connection.query('SELECT *, FROM `bosses` where u=? and p=AES_DECRYPT (?, 'ENCRYPTIONKEY')', [req.body.user,req.body.pass], function (error, results, fields) {
```

but somehow I can't get it to work properly. Should I use a placeholder for the encryption key too ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies and explanation on why this was generally a bad idea :)

Here is a variation: no decryption password is stored in the code:

```
connection.query('SELECT *, AES_DECRYPT(p, ?) AS `key` FROM bosses WHERE u = ?', [req.body.pass,  req.body.user], function (error, results, fields) {

console.log (req.body.pass + req.body.user )

    

if(results[0].key){
                session.loggedin=1;
                res.redirect('/zirkus');
            }else{
                res.redirect('/soccer');
            }
        });


});
```

Here the admin user types the decryption password in the form and if the decryption is successful (the key returns true) it allows the user to log in (without using or saving the password) else access is denied.

I assume that in this solution the only downside are the mysql logs right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use doubole quotes for the decryption key or escaping ut

```
connection.query('SELECT *, FROM `bosses` where u=? and p=AES_DECRYPT (?, "ENCRYPTIONKEY)', [req.body.user,req.body.pass], function (error, results, fields) {
           if(results.length){
                session.loggedin=1;
                res.redirect('/zirkus');
            }else{
                res.redirect('/soccer');
            }
        });
```

But as in every language passwords are usually only stored as **hashed** values, so that they can't be easily reconstructed, even with the logs. so chelkc for example https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/using-bcrypt-to-hash-and-check-passwords-in-node-js

Comment: thanks for your reply. See my edit. Is it still a bad idea or usable ?

Comment: Use hashed values, then the logs doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1:** Don't use encryption for storing user passwords. Use hashing.

There's no reason you need to decrypt user passwords, ever. Instead, when the user logs in, you hash their input with the same hashing function and compare the result to the hash string stored in the database.

Try bcrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Also read https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

**Answer 2:** I never do encryption *or* hashing in SQL expressions. The reason is that the if you use the query log, it will contain the plaintext of the sensitive content, as it appears in SQL expressions. It will also be visible in the PROCESSLIST.

Instead, if you need to do encryption or hashing of sensitive content, do it in your application code, and then use the result in SQL statements.

---

Re your edit:

> I assume that in this solution the only downside are the mysql logs right ?

No. The problem is that you're storing the password using reversible encryption. There is no reason to reverse a user password. If I visit a website that offers a "password recovery" feature where they can tell me what my password was (no matter how many other security checks they do), then I know they're storing passwords wrong.

If passwords are stored in a reversible encrypted format, this creates the possibility that someone else other than me can reverse the encryption and read my password. That will never happen with hashing, because you can't reverse hashing to get the original content.

> If it is because of the logs ... ?

You could disable the query logs, of course. But there's also other places where the query is visible, such as:

- the binary log (if you use statement-based binary logs)
- the PROCESSLIST
- the performance_schema statement tables
- the MySQL network protocol. That is, if you don't use TLS to encrypt the connection between the application and the database, someone could intercept packets on the network and see the plaintext query with the plaintext content.

In your edited example, they could view the user's plaintext decryption key in any of the above contexts.

> ... why MySQL has this function ...?

There are legitimate uses of encryption other than user passwords. Sometimes you do need to decrypt encrypted content. I'm just talking about user passwords. User passwords can be authenticated without decryption, as I described at the top of this answer. It's covered in the blog I linked to, and also as a chapter in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Another use of encryption and corresponding decryption function in SQL is when you develop code as stored procedures. It would be inconvenient to have to return encrypted data to the client application just to decrypt it, and then send it back to your stored procedures for further processing it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. See my edit. Is it still a bad idea or usable ? If it is because of the logs, why MySQL has this function ..just to decrypt on the top of a hashed password ?